# android compatible algorithm for PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1

Tags: android

I am developing an android application in which i need to decrypt files encrypted by my c# project. the Problem is that i can do the same for java project but in android it is throwing exception. the help will be very much appreciated if anyone tell me the PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 compatible algorithm for android. 
   Thanks!

Comment: any Luck? I also have an same issue while my program generating and exception java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SecretKeyFactory PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 implementation not found: and looking for solution still.

Answer (score 0):

C#? Are you using Mono for Android?

I think someone out there said that the BouncyCastle library that Android comes with has a lot of stuff stripped out, including PBKDF2. However , some nice people out there created SpongyCastle so that you can use BC alongside SC. SpongyCastle is BouncyCastle but with the class names renamed